# Is it now a good time to merge with CSTheory.SE

Tags: discussion

For several recent years, the contents of questions on CSTheory.SE are strict subsets of those here on CS.SE

Especially, theoretical questions here and there are often linked to each other. Also, many have asked a question on both sites. Then moderator actions like close, merge, migrate have to be taken. *Very much work to do in between just 2 sites*.

Maybe more importantly, practical questions here on CS.SE are rarely allowed on CSTheory.SE

**So, why do we need to maintain a tiny site like CSTheory.SE while everything would be simpler and cleaner by merging it to this site CS.SE**?

Personally, I hope for a **happy merging** event in **far future**.

*Sorry if this question annoys CSTheory.SE site's moderators*.

Comment: a) This discussion should be on [meta.cstheory.SE]. b) This has been discussed heatedly back when; did you read those discussions? c) The overlap affects relatively few users of [cs.SE]. d) Historically, many users of [cstheory.SE] have expressed that they have no interest in the broader [cs.SE].

Comment: **a**) Since CST.SE moderators historically declines this idea, we do not hope to revert their minds in several years to go. I post here just to consider this possibility in **far future**. b) I have read it, CST.SE mods insist on the highly-renowned class of the questions there c) Yes, practical concerns always outnumber theoretical ones **d**) This is our **hope**. Gradually, our site gains much more attention from the theoretical community. And going to far future with this trend, it is a right choice to merge the 2 sites. In short, point a) and point d) are very interesting and hopeful.

Comment: I don't follow. What do you hope to achieve by opening the discussion _now_? A merge will never happen without the express wish of the [cstheory.SE] community. (Except if SE overruled them (and us), which I don't expect to happen.)

Comment: Nothing concrete at all to try to achieve for myself, I would say. At least, one of my objective is to find out whether **this ambitious idea is still out there waiting to become reality**.

Comment: CS Theory moderator here --- I don't find the question annoying! You're welcome to bring it up on CS Theory Meta. There are some arguments both for and against. It's not up to moderators to decide, in any case.

Comment: I always saw CS-SE as a less bloated [Mathematics-SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), while TCS would be analogous to [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/tour).

Answer (score 9):

I can see some logic in that.  However, that would need the consent and enthusiastic support of CSTheory, so I think this is something you'd need to ask on the CSTheory meta, rather than here.  Personally, it doesn't seem very likely to me.

Let me also share a personal perspective on Stack Exchange sites.  In my opinion, a Stack Exchange site is defined not solely by the list of topics that are on-topic there.  At least as important, it is defined by its community (and their values).  The CSTheory community is pretty different from ours (though of course with some overlap), and their site serves a mostly different audience.

Background reading to provide some context on the history: I encourage you to read [How is this subdomain different than cstheory.stackexchange.com?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/755), [What is the history of the Computer Science site?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/215/755), [How to make our cs community very different from the cstheory?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/78/755), https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/947/5038.